# Website intermittent load failure - something wrong with DNS?

Tags: django, heroku, web, dns, cloudflare

Quick overview:

- Developed web app with Python and Django; developed and tested locally; adjusted settings to harden for deployment
- Deployed app to Heroku for simple hosting platform; tested and worked successfully
- Purchased hobby hosting on Heroku so deployed app would not sleep; I can still verify this to be true, the app loads instantly at myappname.herokuapp.com
- Purchased domain name on GoDaddy
- Used a free CloudFlare account to manage DNS
- Entire chain of operation works successfully *sometimes*, but sometimes I get a website coming soon page:

[image: website_coming_soon]

So when I go to bed last night, everything works.  I can load the app from the purchased domain name on all my computers and mobile devices.  I wake up this morning, and I'm once again getting the coming soon page.  No matter how many times I refresh, and with cache disabled in Chrome so I know it's not my browser.

Everything is working perfectly on the Heroku side, since I can load the app there every single time.  Once I told GoDaddy to use Cloudflare's nameservers I think there can't be an issue on GoDaddy's side.  There has to be something with Cloudflare.

The DNS settings on Cloudflare are super simple:

- CNAME for my.url pointing to my.url.herokudns.com
- CNAME for www as an alias of my.url

The hardest part is that it just sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  I can't nail this down.

Comment: Can you share a real domain name?

Comment: Yeah I was a little hesitant but it is simply "cait.rocks". For now it should just load a list of recipes and that's it.

Comment: Thanks. Your DNS settings look fine, the cait.rocks opens ok from my location but www.cait.rocks shows Heroku default page (so you probably need to add it as another [custom domain name](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain), in heroku settings)